# How to debug runtime error 13 type mismatch?

Tags: vba

I need to rename the files in a multiple folders.If the file name is "1" or "main" or "MAIN" I want to rename it differently. The code works properly if I want to rename all the files but now its showing type mismatch error.

```
Sub rename()

    Dim fso, fsoFolder, fsoFile, strPath, strName, fsoSubFolder, i, a

    i = 1

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\anu\Desktop\Black")

    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders

        For Each fsoFile In fsoSubFolder.Files

            strName = fsoFile.Name
            strPath = Left(fsoFile.Path, Len(fsoFile.Path) - Len(strName))
            a = fsoFile.Name
            If a = "main" Or "Main" Or "MAIN" Or "1" Then
                fso.CopyFile strPath & strName, strPath & fsoSubFolder.Name & "_" & "Main" & ".jpg"
                fso.DeleteFile strPath & strName
            Else
                fso.CopyFile strPath & strName, strPath & fsoSubFolder.Name & "_" & i & ".jpg"
                fso.DeleteFile strPath & strName
                i = i + 1
            End If

        Next
        i = 1
    Next

End Sub
```

How do I check that condition without getting that error?

Comment: Can you tell me where it breaks?

Comment: Its not running at all. It just shows the runtime error 13. If I remove the part from If to Else ie without checking that condition it works fine.

Comment: This -> `If a = "main" Or "Main" Or "MAIN" Or "1" Then` does not test `a` against each.

Comment: How do I check that condition ?

Comment: try this If a = "main" Or a= "Main" Or a="MAIN" Or a="1"

Comment: Easier: `If UCase(a) = "MAIN" or a = "1"` -- this handles any possible lower/upper-case combination in the word "main".

Comment: *Its not running at all.* Yes it is, otherwise you wouldn't get an error. When you get the error, press the button to `Debug`, this should highlight the line which is raising the error. Cheers.

Comment: David is correct - it's very important you be able to get it to the line it's breaking on(I just tap F8 and step through).  Your issue may lie in the fact that you're only doing 1 comparison on a and the rest are type mismatches(not boolean values).  So it's looking at `or "1"` and not able to match that to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed this and it's work fine for me. try:

```
Sub rename()

    Dim fso, fsoFolder, fsoFile, strPath, strName, fsoSubFolder, i, a

    i = 1

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\anu\Desktop\Black")

    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders

        For Each fsoFile In fsoSubFolder.Files

            strName = fsoFile.Name
            strPath = Left(fsoFile.Path, Len(fsoFile.Path) - Len(strName))
            a = fsoFile.Name
            If ((a = "main") Or (a = "Main") Or (a = "MAIN") Or (a = "1")) Then '-----Line changed-----
                fso.CopyFile strPath & strName, strPath & fsoSubFolder.Name & "_" & "Main" & ".jpg"
                fso.DeleteFile strPath & strName
            Else
                fso.CopyFile strPath & strName, strPath & fsoSubFolder.Name & "_" & i & ".jpg"
                fso.DeleteFile strPath & strName
                i = i + 1
            End If

        Next
        i = 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is likely giving you the issue. (without any additional information)

```
Dim fso, fsoFolder, fsoFile, strPath, strName, fsoSubFolder, i, a
```

As a best practice you should get in the habit of typing all your variables, especially any objects that need to be `Set` in the code.

Something like this instead (you may need to confirm the types as I don't know exactly what they should be)

```
Dim fso as 'insert your object here
Dim fsoFolder as 'insert your object here
Dim fsoFile as 'insert your object here
Dim strPath as String
Dim strName as String
Dim fsoSubFolder as  'insert your object here
Dim i as Integer
Dim a as String
```